# How to re-open the port?

Tags: iptables, port, filter

I've a server with root access, I opened the 4022 port for ssh and it was working very well before, Today I try to connect on my server via ssh, but nothing happened, so I checked that via nmap and it's show me 4022 is filtered , so how can I open it again ?

 I test this,

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 4022 -j ACCEPT
```

but it's not work again ?!

Comment: Have you checked if SSH is running on port 4022? And how did you open it before?

Comment: Yeah it's running, I even restart ssh service but didn't work...

Comment: how did you open it before?

Comment: I set the 4022 on sshd_config and wrote "/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 4022 -j ACCEPT" then I restart the sshd service

Comment: May be you can print your iptables rules with: `iptables -S` and check it.

Answer (score 3):

It is often the case that the last rule in the INPUT chain is one that REJECTs or DROPs a packet unconditionally. When you use `-A` it causes the rule to be added to the end of the chain. This often means that it gets ignored because there is an earlier rule that is matched **and** that has a terminating target - at which point rule processing stops.

Try Inserting the rule at the beginning of the chain

```
/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 4022 -j ACCEPT
```